# How to uncheck all other checkbox if data is "No Preference"?

Tags: react-native

How do I uncheck all checkbox if the data is no preference? I don't know how to manipulate the data.

This is the index.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { CheckBox } from 'react-native-elements';

import { Colors } from '../../../themes/';

import style          from "./style";

class CCheckBox extends React.Component {

  /////////////////////////////
    // constructor()
    /////////////////////////////
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    console.log('custom/ccheckbox/index.js constructor()');
    this.state = {
      checked: false,
    };
  }

  /////////////////////////////
    // handleCheck()
    /////////////////////////////
  handleCheck() {
    this.setState({ selectedCheckbox }); // update selected item
         }

     render() {

    return (
      <CheckBox
        iconType='material'
        checkedIcon='check'
        uncheckedIcon='check-box-outline-blank'
        checkedColor={Colors.ORANGE}
        checked={this.state.checked}
        containerStyle={style.content}
        onPress={() => this.handleCheck()}
      />
    );
    }
    }

    export default CCheckBox;
```

And this is my profalcoholpref.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ScrollView, View } from 'react-native';
import { Content } from 'native-base';
import CButton        from '../cbutton/index';
import PopSelectList  from './popselectlist';

import styleC         from "../../common/style";
import style          from "./style";

class PopAlcoholPref extends React.Component {

  ///////////////////////////////
    // constructor()
  ///////////////////////////////
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    console.log('custom/cfield/popalcoholpref.js constructor()');
    this.state = {
      selectedCheckbox: {},
      visible: this.props.visible,
      data: [
        {
          id          : 1,
          code        : 'DON',
          description : 'Do not drink',
        },
        {
          id          : 2,
          code        : 'INF',
          description : 'Infrequently',
        },
        {
          id          : 3,
          code        : 'SOC',
          description : 'Socially',
        },
        {
          id          : 4,
          code        : 'MOD',
          description : 'Moderately',
        },
        {
          id          : 5,
          code        : 'ASN',
          description : 'As Needed',
        },
        {
          id          : 5,
          code        : 'NOP',
          description : 'No Preference',
        },
      ]
    };

  }

  ///////////////////////////////
    // componentWillReceiveProps()
  ///////////////////////////////
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    console.log('componentWillReceiveProps()');
    this.setState({
      visible: nextProps.visible
    });
  }

  ///////////////////////////////
    // handleSave()
  ///////////////////////////////
  handleSave() {
    console.log('handleSave()');
    this.setState({
      visible: false
    });
  }

  ///////////////////////////////
    // render()
  ///////////////////////////////
  render() {

    return (
      <View>
        <PopSelectList title='Alcohol Preference' data={this.state.data} visible={this.state.visible} handleSave={() => this.handleSave()} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default PopAlcoholPref;
```

How do I uncheck all other checkbox if no preference is checked? Is there any way I can manipulate the data? Index.js is the frontend and I manipulated the checkbox there and in the prefalcohol is where the data is being stored.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a bit of a refactoring here I beleive.

You should move the state handling logic to the list. In the list you can manipulate all the checkboxes at the same time.

```
class List extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checkBoxesList: [{
        id: 1,
        checked: false,
      }, {
        id: 2,
        checked: false,
      }]
    }
  }

  unCheckAll() {
    this.setState({ checkBoxesList: this.state.checkBoxesList.map(({ id }) => ({
      id: id,
      checked: false,
    })) })
  }

  checkBoxSelected(id) {
    const index = this.state.checkBoxesList.findIndex((value) => value.id === id);
    this.setState({ checkBoxesList[index]: { 
      ...this.state.checkBoxesList[index],
      checked: !this.state.checkBoxesList[index].checked 
    })
  }

  renderCheckBoxes() {
    return this.state.checkBoxesList.map(({id, checked}) => (
      <CheckBox id={id} checked={checked} onPress={this.checkBoxSelected} />
    ))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        {this.renderCheckBoxes()}
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

So this Component handles the states for the checkboxes. You need to make sure that you also implement the callback inside the CheckBox component for the OnPress method. Now calling the UncheckAll method will uncheck all the checkboxes.
But also you have to put in some extra check before setting the checkBoxesList if the index does exist.

Comment: The creation of data and the checkbox are at different files sir.